# Jquery click toggle function animated menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, click, toggle

I don't know how to make something like that the ul.list slides down after first click and slide up after second click with using .animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listopen").click().toggle(
    function() {
        $(".list").animate({top:"0px"});
    },
    function() {
        $(".list").animate({top:"-120px"});
    },
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ul class="listopen">Click
    <li class="list">Test</li>
    <li class="list">Test2</li>
        </ul>

$('.listopen').click(function() 
{    
    $(".list").toggle(function() 
    {
    $(this).animate({
            top:"150px"
        });
    }, function() 
    {
    $(this).animate({
            top:"-150px"
        });
    });


   });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/b9386fk1/